# why wont sed read these variables properly?

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I am currently trying to use sed to find and replace some text in a file, and for the terms that are being found/replaced, I am trying to use variables, but I cannot get them to work properly for some reason. The variables consist of c1-c9, which can be seen below:

```
    c1=$( echo "start time;project_start_time" )
    c2=$( echo "start_time;project_start_time" )
    c3=$( echo "end time;project_end_time" )
    c4=$( echo "end_time;project_end_time" )
    c5=$( echo "total time;project_total_time" )
    c6=$( echo "total_time;project_total_time" )
    c7=$( echo "project_id;project_ID" )
    c8=$( echo "status;project_status" )
    c9=$( echo "client_id;client_ID" )
    c10=$( echo "employee_id;employee_ID" )
    c11=$( echo "employee_name;employee_name" )
    c12=$( echo "date created;date_created" )
    c13=$( echo "date_created;date_created" )
```

and the code that contains the sed part is:

```
 while [ "$countc" -le 13 ]; do
                    real_string=$( eval echo "\$c$countc" | cut -d ';' -f 2 )
                    nc_string=$( eval echo "\$c$countc" | cut -d ';' -f 1 )
                    sed -e "s/$nc_string/$real_string/gI" phasef/"$count"p.csv #> phasef/"$count".csv
                    countc=$(( $countc + 1 ))
            done
```

(there is more code to the script, but it is irrelevant) When I run the script, if i tell it to output real_string/nc_string as the while loop moves along, the variables are correctly outputted, real_string/nc_string variables are actually being defined correctly, but I am not sure why sed is not reading them correctly. If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it as I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now, thanks!

Comment: sed command looks fine..can you try to print the content of the file phasef/"$count"p.csv before the sed command and check ?

Comment: @Guru unfortunately I still seem to be getting the same behavior when I issue the following: cat phasef/"$count"p.csv | sed -e "s/$nc_string/$real_string/gI"

Comment: Well, technically it's Bash expanding those variables, not sed. Have you verified that $nc_string and $real_string are as you expect?

Comment: @tjameson yep I've verified those multiple times

Comment: Try `set -x`. It prints all commands before they're executed. May be helpful...

Comment: `sed is not reading them correctly` <-- this doesn't tell much about what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the echo for "s/$nc_string/$real_string/gI" & it is expanding the variables properly. Please let us know, the input file contents.

I suspect that, highlited part in below line has some issue.

sed -e "s/$nc_string/$real_string/gI" **phasef/"$count"p.csv > phasef/"$count".csv**

If you want to replace all pairs in input file (`phasef/${count}p.csv`) & save to output file (`phasef/$count.csv`), use below code:

```
cp phasef/"$count"p.csv phasef/"$count".csv
while [ "$countc" -le 13 ]; do
    real_string=$( eval echo "\$c$countc" | cut -d ';' -f 2 )
    nc_string=$( eval echo "\$c$countc" | cut -d ';' -f 1 )
    sed -i -e "s/$nc_string/$real_string/gI"  phasef/"$count".csv
    countc=$(( $countc + 1 ))
done
```

Note the `-i` in sed line.

Comment: this did the trick, thanks! was stuck on this one so I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3):

I think @anishsane probably has the right answer. I just want to offer some notes about your code. If you're using bash, take advantage of some of bash's features:

1) just assign a string instead of spawning a subshell to echo the string:

```
c1="start time;project_start_time"
```

(unless the `echo` is just a placeholder here for some more complicated process

2) use an array instead of numerically-indexed variables

```
c=(
     "start time;project_start_time"
     "start_time;project_start_time"
     "end time;project_end_time"
     "end_time;project_end_time"
     "total time;project_total_time"
     "total_time;project_total_time"
     "project_id;project_ID"
     "status;project_status"
     "client_id;client_ID"
     "employee_id;employee_ID"
     "employee_name;employee_name"
     "date created;date_created"
     "date_created;date_created" 
)
```

3) split the strings with read and IFS and avoid eval nastiness:

```
for (( countc=1; countc <= ${#c[@]}; countc++ )); do
    IFS=';' read nc_string real_string <<< "${c[countc]}"
    # ...
done
```

Comment: thanks for your tips! will have to utilize them, the eval especially, I've only just started having the need to use eval so it will be good to have a better way to do stuff such as that from the start

Comment: "just assign a string instead of spawning a subshell to echo the string": Well, you need it (only) in special cases, e.g. when you need to print ANSI escape characters.

Comment: read up on bash's [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the sed line. Change

```
sed -e "s/$nc_string/$real_string/gI" phasef/"$count"p.csv
```

to

```
sed -e "s/$nc_string/$real_string/gI" phasef/"$countc"p.csv
```

Comment: I think, this is not what @lacrosse1991 wants. I don't expect having 13 separate input files & output files, per sed expression pair.